# Creating a view for SpatiaLite in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, spatialite

I can create SpatiaLite layers from SpatiaLite tables.  However, I would like to create a layer based on a SpatiaLite view.  I click on "Configure new Sql View" from the "New Layer" screen.  Then I am able to create the sql view.  However, after I create the new layer based on a SpatiaLite view, I cannot get queries to run against the SpatiaLite table.  If I go into the newly created layer, I click on "Edit sql view", I type in a known working sql for this SpatiaLite db such as:

```
select * from lines
```

Then under Attributes, I click on "Refresh" and it shows no fields.  Also if I click on "Layer Preview", select the layer and click on GML, I get the following error:

```
error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.io.IOExceptionjava.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "FROM": syntax error) [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "FROM": syntax error)
```

Somehow it is not finding the sqlite table.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update #1**

I found this in the geoserver.log file:

```
Could not find mapping for 'GEOMETRY', ignoring the column and setting the feature type read only
```

Comment: I think this question is better suited at gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at all the info I found online and it looks to be a limitation of the SpatiaLite provider for GEOSERVER in that it does not allow to create custom views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at all the info I found online and it looks to be a limitation of the SpatiaLite provider for GEOSERVER in that it does not allow to create custom SQL views in GEOSERVER.

Comment: Could you share a link with the information source?

Comment: Feel free to use google and search for it yourself.  Try it yourself and you will see it is not possible to create a custom SpatiaLite sql view in geoserver.

Comment: I was just suggesting you to improve your answer based on http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Suggestions are always welcome. :)